# Не могу реализовать обновление картинки в tkinter. Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, gui, tkinter, pillow

Не могу реализовать обновление картинки. Объясняю сценарий работы:

1. Пользователь решает задание
2. Вылетает окно с результатом
3. Следующее задание

И так по кругу.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import random

base = [["pic.png", "-Ты говоришь по английски? -Да", "-Как тебя зовут? - Да"], ["pic2.png", "Лицо моего инвестора", "Когда я рассказываю ему про блокчейн"]]
n = random.randint(1,1)

def display_result():
    if first.get() == base[n][1] and second.get() == base[n][2]:
        messagebox.showinfo("Memes", "Правильно!")
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo("Memes", "Непраильно( Ответ: \n\n" + base[n][1]  + '\n\n' + base[n][2])

root = Tk()
root.title("Memes")

image = Image.open(base[n][0])
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
label = Label(root, image=photo)
label.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=0, pady=0, sticky="e")

first = StringVar()
second = StringVar()

first_label = Label(text="Первая строка:")
first_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")

second_label = Label(text="Вторая строка:")
second_label.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w")

first_entry = Entry(textvariable=first)
first_entry.grid(row=0,column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

second_entry = Entry(textvariable=second)
second_entry.grid(row=1,column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

button = Button(text="Готово!", command=display_result)
button.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=5, pady=2, sticky="n")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Желательно все-таки уточнить, в чем именно проблема.

Comment: Не знаю как реализовать обновление картинки)

Comment: Картинку вы вешаете на label создайте функцию где будет меняться картинка. label["image"] = photo

Comment: А можно конкретный пример?

Comment: Сейчас накатаю )

Comment: Благадарю вас) Завтра утром взгляну. Кстати, говнокод у меня или что то болеемение суразное?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Вот более или менее суразное)**

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.title('Смена фона')
        self.geometry('320x345+300+300')

        new_image_black = Image.new("RGB", (320, 320), (0, 0, 0))
        new_image_black.save("black.png", "PNG")

        new_image_red = Image.new("RGB", (320, 320), (255, 0, 0))
        new_image_red.save("red.png", "PNG")

        black = Image.open("black.png")
        black_bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(black)

        self.label = Label(self, image=black_bg)
        self.label.image = black_bg
        self.label.pack()

        button = Button(self, text="Сменить фон", command=self.to_change_the_background)
        button.pack()

    def to_change_the_background(self):
        red = Image.open("red.png")
        red_bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(red)
        self.label["image"] = red_bg
        self.label.image = red_bg

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Я не знаю ООП в питоне. Можно на примере моего кода) Заранее спасибо

Comment: +В моём случае это не прменимо т.к. мне нужно менять картинку постоянно.

Comment: Здесь более чем достаточно материала

Comment: Ну вроде как разобрался

Comment: Если вам помог мой ответ отметьте его.